# How to extract the output of an intermediate layer in Keras [for R]?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am having trouble extracting the output of an intermediate layer in a Keras NN model. Although there is a ton of resource on this most of them are geared towards for python users. I have tried working towards the tutorial posted [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18751/r-keras-how-to-get-output-of-a-hidden-layer) and [here](https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/faq.html#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-). Essentially both of the tutorial says to recreate the original model and then somehow extract the intermediate layers by simply calling it. The issue I am having is `model$input` returns nothing in my code and I have no idea where `layer_name` is in a model. After playing around with this method I tried creating a new model to the layer I am interested in and put in the trained weights of the original model in order to get the intermediate layer output. However, I found myself at a lack of resource for R users on how to place weights into a new model. I would appreciate if anyone would help with walking through a concrete example on how to do either method or a better one. Here is my original model:

```
network <- keras_model_sequential() 
network %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu", input_shape = length(training_data) ) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 8, activation = "sigmoid" ) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu" ) %>%
  layer_dense(units = length(training_data), activation = "softmax")
```

Comment: Not a lot of takers.  Sad.  I'm looking.  If I find it then I will let you know. This looks like a decent start. [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18751/r-keras-how-to-get-output-of-a-hidden-layer)